# Как получить значение многомерного массива по ключу из строки?

Tags: php

В функцию приходит строка типо `'key1.key2'` и массив, надо вернуть значение по данному "адресу", как это можно сделать по красивей?

```
function arr($arr, $get) {
    // Магия
}

echo arr([
    'key1' => [
        'key2' => 123
    ]
], 'key1.key2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
function arr($arr, $get) {
  $idxs = explode('.', $get);
  foreach ($idxs as $idx)
    $arr = $arr[$idx];
  return $arr;
}
```